# Perl List context as hash key

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, casting

I have a variable which I want to take the first capture and use that as the key for a hash. I found a solution but it seems suboptimal.

```
My $out  = $hash{[$var =~ /(^[a-z]+)/]->[0]};
```

It’s seems like there has to be a better way then going list->array->scalar. Maybe just list->scalar. I know that I could also capture in another variable and then use that as a key, but I want to avoid that. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your code does not compile. Also always use warnings and strict. `%hash{key}` should issue a warning `%hash{"key"} in scalar context better written as $hash{"key"}`

Comment: Sorry. Copied this from memory. Original code used $hash. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to cram everything into a single statement

```
my ($key) = $var =~ /(^[a-z]+)/;
my $out   = $hash{ $key };
```

but something like this would be okay

```
my $out;
$out = $hash{$1} if $var =~ /(^[a-z]+)/;
```

or possibly

```
my $out = $var =~ /(^[a-z]+)/ && $hash{$1};
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to create an array reference.

```
my $out = $hash{ ($var =~ m/(^[a-z]+)/)[0] };
```

Answer (score 0):

What´s wrong with?

```
$var =~ /^([a-z]+)/;
my $out = $hash{$1};
```

It is useful to use the output of `=~` in list context for more than one match, but for a single one?

If you are expecting the regex to not match (as suggested by other people), it will be better to check first. For instance:

```
if( $var =~ /^([a-z]+)/ ) {
  my $out = $hash{$1};
  ...
}
```

If you want a one-liner, you may use:

```
my $out = $hash{ ($var =~ /^([a-z]+)/)[0] };
```

This will give a warning if the regex does not match. It was suggested first by @tinita.

Comment: You shouldn't use the value of `$1` unless you know that the pattern match succeeded. `$out = $hash{$1} if $var =~ /(^[a-z]+)/` as I wrote in my own answer.

Comment: I agree with you for the most general case. But then, how would you know you can use the value of `$out` after that? A more general case would use `if( $var =~ /^([a-z]+)/ ) { my $out = $hash{$1}; ... }`, don´t you think?

Comment: If you're talking about my answer then the intention was to follow up with `if ( $out ) { ... }`. It may be better to base the whole thing on the regex, or it may not. We have only a tiny view on the OP's application. It may even be better to `die qq{Malformed data "$var"} unless $var =~ /(^[a-z]+)/` but we cannot tell.

Comment: @JavierElices your first code might end up with a wrong result, if the regex doesn't match, and `$1` still contains something from a previous regex. That's why one shouldn't do that, like @Borodin said. And your second code is a copy of mine :-/

Comment: Sorry, @tinita, I had not seen your answer when I wrote mine. Also, regarding safety, that line `my $out = $hash{ ($var =~ /^([a-z]+)/)[0] };` will also fail if the regex does not match.

Comment: @JavierElices in case the regex doesn't match, the oneliner will produce a warning `Use of uninitialized value in hash element`, and `$out` will be left undef (unless there's an empty key in the hash for that purpose). IMHO that's much safer than quietly producing the wrong result!

Comment: @tinita, I have edited the answer to reflect your suggestion and Borodin's. Thank you both!